# 400 Bad request on images

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to link an image that is used as logo inside my JSP page. I'm getting a 400 bad request error in my browser. The img tag is given below

```
<img src="/img/aws-shd-en.png">
```

My folder structure is as given below.

[image: Folder structure of my project]

I get the same issue when I'm trying to link external js ans css in the page too. What am I doing wrong here how to avoid the 400 error and show the image in my page

The application is run in localhost. Please see the screen shot below with the errors

[image]

Comment: Could you link to the problem page in question?

Answer (score 0):

There are more things wrong here:

1. Your images are in `/WEB-INF/img` folder, not in `/img`. Anyway, you should get "404 Not Found" for that, not "400 Bad Request".
2. Unless your web application is deployed in ROOT context, you should add a call to `request.getContextPath()` before any URL within your app, i.e. `<img src="${request.getContextPath()}/img/image.png" />` instead of `<img src="/img/image.png" />`.
3. Do not put images (and other static content) into `WEB-INF` folder - this folder is by default not accessible via HTTP request ("from browser"), you would have to implement your own way to serve it (e.g. custom servlet).

Comment: I'm getting 400 error see the screen shot in the question. I placed the folder outside WEB-INF and used the context path then I got 404

Comment: What servlet container do you use, Tomcat? And which version?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7, I'm running it using maven.